C# Polly.Core choose pipeline based on Http request URI
in the old version of Polly, I used this function to get a policy based on the request URI:
private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> PolicySelector(IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string> policyRegistry,
    HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)
{
    Guard.Against.Null(httpRequestMessage);
    Guard.Against.Null(httpRequestMessage.RequestUri);

    if (httpRequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Contains(_consentsSettings.GetConsentsRequestUri))
    {
        return policyRegistry.Get<IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>>(Constants.PollyPipelineKey.GetConsents);
    }

    if (httpRequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Contains(_consentsSettings.SetConsentsRequestUri))
    {
        return Policy.NoOpAsync<HttpResponseMessage>();
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Polly policy for consents not found");
}

and on my HttpClient, I called this with the following code:
services.AddHttpClient(ConsentsService.ConsentsClientName, client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUri);
})
.AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry(PolicySelector);

Now, I would like to use the new Polly.Core package. I have this code:
services.AddHttpClient(ConsentsService.ConsentsClientName, client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUri);
})
.AddResilienceHandler(Constants.PollyPipelineKey.GetConsents, (builder, context) =>
{
    var factory = context.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpPollyPipelineFactory>();
    var pipeline = factory.CreateResiliencePipeline();

    builder.AddPipeline(pipeline);
})

But I don't know if it is possible to apply this resilience handler only when calling a specific URI, or if the only solution is to check the URI before the client call to PostAsync and wrap it with the pipeline's ExecuteAsync method.I hope I was clear. Thanks

At the time of writing, there is no AddResilienceHandler overload which allows you to access the HttpRequestMessage. So, currently you can't do the exact same branching during the pipeline registration like what you did in case of Polly V7.
BUT, there are two things worth mentioning.
SelectPipelineByAuthority
There is an extension method called SelectPipelineByAuthority. This method caches and assigns pipeline for each authority (schema + protocol + port). This feature was designed mainly for circuit breakers but can be used elsewhere as well.
Here we have documented how to use it.
Multiple named clients
You could register multiple named clients. One which is decorated with your resilience pipeline the other without it.
Here the key thing is to find meaningful and expressive names to ease the selection of the proper client for given use cases.

UPDATE #1
There is a workaround. Since 8.2.0 the Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Resilience package exposes the ResilienceHandler class, which was internal before this release.
This class has a ctor which allows you to access the request and define which pipeline you want to use. With that you can do something like this:
services
    .AddHttpClient(ConsentsService.ConsentsClientName, client => { ... })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => new ResilienceHandler(req => YourPipelineSelector(sp, req)));

The NoOp equivalent for V8 is the ResiliencePipeline.Empty.

Thank you for your suggestion. The problem is that ResilienceHandler gives me an error because it has this attribute: [Experimental("EXTEXP0001", UrlFormat = "https://aka.ms/dotnet-extensions-warnings/{0}")]. I think that I should create my own custom ResilienceHandler. What do you think?

@pampua84 This ExperimentalAttribute was introduced in .NET 8. You don't have to create your own custom ResilienceHandler just suppress the warning like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/experimental-overview

However, Microsoft documentation states: "You may use experimental APIs in your application, but we advise against using these APIs in production scenarios as they may not be fully tested nor fully reliable." So I'm a bit confused about its use.

@pampua84 There is an open PR to remove this attribute (https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/5669, https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/pull/5670) that's why I suggested to suppress the warning in the meanwhile.
